# Send email to multiple addresses on Contact Form 7, but exclude personal details on all but one

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

I am building a site in Divi for a business that compares coach hire prices. The email should send the users details to both the client and the list of coach providers he works with, but with one exception.

When the email is sent, he only wants the users personal details to be sent to him (name and email) and the rest of the information captured in the form (pick up time, pickup address etc etc) to be sent to the coach companies.

So to clarify, the client wants to receive all of the information to be sent to his email address, but when it is sent to the coach companies, he wants all of the information sent to them  except for their contact information. This way, it stops the coach companies contacting the user directly to give them a price. The reason for this is the coach companies will come back to him with a price and he will pick the best price and then contact the user himself, effectively the middle man.

The URL of the site is quotemycoach.e1.tacb.wales where you can see the form on the homepage

Hopefully I've made sense, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Contact Form 7 lets you set up multiple outgoing emails. Set the outgoing message for the 'everyone-except-one', and a 2nd outgoing message for 'just-the-one'.

And use the BCC feature to keep everyone's email confidential. Info on how to do that is on the CF7 site and support forums.....which is where you should ask for support on plugins.